# Aggregating column value and update in new column

Tags: pyspark

I want to aggregate a column and sum up values of specific column. Which I want to add as part of
same DataFrame for further calculations.

I have achieved in this way

```
travelGroup = travel.groupBy("day" ).agg(sum("action").cast("int").alias('dayCount'))
travel = travel.join(travelGroup, ['day'],  "left_outer").na.fill(0)
```

But, would like to check this is the right way or any other optimised way to perform this process.

> travel - Dataframe

---

```
+---------+---+  
| day    | action
+---------
| TUE    | 5
| WED    | 7
| TUE    | 2
| FRI    | 1
| TUE    | 6
| SUN    | 3
```

> Result - dataframe

```
+---------+---+  +---+  
| day    | action | dayCount
+---------------------
| TUE    | 5      | 13
| WED    | 7      | 7
| TUE    | 2      | 13
| FRI    | 1      | 4
| TUE    | 6      | 13
| FRI    | 3      | 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak Window Function to do this.
One Example found over internet is -

```
case class Salary(depName: String, empNo: Long, salary: Long)
val empsalary = Seq(
  Salary("sales", 1, 5000),
  Salary("personnel", 2, 3900),
  Salary("sales", 3, 4800),
  Salary("sales", 4, 4800),
  Salary("personnel", 5, 3500),
  Salary("develop", 7, 4200),
  Salary("develop", 8, 6000),
  Salary("develop", 9, 4500),
  Salary("develop", 10, 5200),
  Salary("develop", 11, 5200)).toDS

val byDepName = Window.partitionBy('depName)
empsalary.withColumn("avg", avg('salary) over byDepName).show
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Window.html

Pyspark Window Function - https://www.arundhaj.com/blog/calculate-difference-with-previous-row-in-pyspark.html